# std::cin loops even if I call ignore() and clear()

Tags: c++, cin

I'm trying to setup an input checking loop so it continuously ask the user for a valid (integer) input, but it seems to get trapped in an infinite loop.

I've searched for solutions and tried to `ignore()` and `clear()`, but it still doesn't stop.

Could you please correct me where I'm wrong here?

```
int num;
cin >> num;
while (cin.fail()) {
  cin.ignore();
  cin.clear();
  cout << "Enter valid number: " << endl;
  cin >> num;
}
```

Comment: Your title is not accurate to the code posted; you're not doing `clear()` and `ignore()`; you're doing `ignore()` and `clear()`. Order is important.

Comment: BTW, `cin.clear` does not clear the input buffer; only the status flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the stream is in an state of error,

```
  cin.ignore();
```

does not do anything. You need to call `cin.clear()` first before calling `cin.ignore()`.

Also, `cin.ignore()` will ignore just one character. To ignore a line of input, use:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Add

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std::numeric_limits`.

The fixed up block of code will look something like:

```
int num;
while ( !(cin >> num) ) {
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
   cout << "Enter valid number: " << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ignore()` has no effect when the stream is in fail state, so do the `clear()` first.